# How write the lines of code in just one line

Tags: r

I would like to know if I can write the lines of code in just one line?

```
library(dplyr)

Test <- structure(list(date2 = structure(c(18808, 18808, 18809, 18810
), class = "Date"), Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
GR = c(0, 1, 0, 1),
coef1 = c(445.23231, 1.31231, 6.32323, 1.232),coef2 = c(8.3231, 3.3432, 1.3233, NA)), 
row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
   
selection = startsWith(names(Test), "coef")

Test[selection][is.na(Test[selection])] = 0 

    Test<-Test %>% filter(GR != 0)

       date2 Category GR   coef1  coef2
1 2021-06-30      ABC  1 1.31231 3.3432
2 2021-07-02      ABC  1 1.23200 0.0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating objects 'selection', do this in a pipe

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Test %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('coef'), replace_na, 0)) %>%
    filter(GR != 0)
```

-output

```
       date2 Category GR   coef1  coef2
1 2021-06-30      ABC  1 1.31231 3.3432
2 2021-07-02      ABC  1 1.23200 0.0000
```

---

Or it may be better to do the `filter` first

```
Test %>% 
   filter(GR != 0) %>% 
   replace(is.na(.), 0)
       date2 Category GR   coef1  coef2
1 2021-06-30      ABC  1 1.31231 3.3432
2 2021-07-02      ABC  1 1.23200 0.0000
```

---

Or in a single line in `base R`

```
transform(subset(Test, GR != 0), coef2 = replace(coef2, is.na(coef2), 0))
       date2 Category GR   coef1  coef2
2 2021-06-30      ABC  1 1.31231 3.3432
4 2021-07-02      ABC  1 1.23200 0.0000
```